# What is the relationship between the special chapters and the regular chapters for Wagatsuma-san wa Ore no Yome?

Tags: wagatsuma-san-wa-ore-no-yome

My understanding is that there are actually two series.

Did the first series, which was in a monthly mag, get the boot?

If so, did the mangaka decide to start over when the series got picked up by the new mag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Japanese Wikipedia](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%88%91%E5%A6%BB%E3%81%95%E3%82%93%E3%81%AF%E4%BF%BA%E3%81%AE%E3%83%A8%E3%83%A1) claims the following:

---

Wagatsuma-san wa Ore no Yome began serialization in [Magazine SPECIAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magazine_Special), and ran in that magazine from the 10th issue of 2011 until the 8th issue of 2012. After that, it was switched to [Weekly Shounen Magazine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weekly_Sh%C5%8Dnen_Magazine), starting in its 42nd issue of 2012. As of this writing, this manga is still being serialized in Weekly Shounen Magazine.

---

Magazine SPECIAL is indeed a monthly, and Weekly Shounen Magazine is (unsurprisingly) a weekly. Both magazines are owned by the publisher Kodansha, so it doesn't look like the manga "got the boot", per se. It looks more like Kodansha figured it was worth running in their flagship magazine rather than the relatively low-circulation Magazine SPECIAL. I guess it had gotten popular enough for that by the time the switch happened, or something.